# Пишу адресную книгу. Представленная ниже функция должна изменять адрес и после этого завершать цикл while. Но почему оператор break не работает?

Tags: python, while, break

```
def change():
    while True:
        ch = input('\tВведите имя контакта чей адресс вы хотите изменить:\n')
        if ch == '':
            print('вы ничего не ввели')

        for c, v in ab.items():
            if c == ch:
                new_address = input('Введите новый адресс:\n')
                ab[c] = new_address
                print('Адресс успешно изменен')
                break
```

Comment: Потому что он завершает цикл `for`, а `while` так и продолжает работать.

Comment: Если `ab` - это словарь (по методам доступа очень похоже), то для того чтобы найти (или не найти) в нём элемент, цикл `for` вообще не нужен (и даже вреден с точки зрения быстродействия).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью `break` можно прервать только самый внутренний цикл. Вам нужно поменять "вечный" цикл `while` на цикл по булевой переменной. Примерно так:

```
def change():
    is_input_mode = True # <--
    while is_input_mode: # <--
        ch = input('\tВведите имя контакта чей адресс вы хотите изменить:\n')
        if ch == '':
            print('вы ничего не ввели')

        for c, v in ab.items():
            if c == ch:
                new_address = input('Введите новый адресс:\n')
                ab[c] = new_address
                print('Адресс успешно изменен')
                is_input_mode = False # <--
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `ab` - это словарь, то цикл `for` вообще тут лишний.

```
def change():
    while True:
        ch = input('\tВведите имя контакта чей адрес вы хотите изменить:\n')
        if ch == '':
            print('Вы ничего не ввели')
        elif ch in ab:
            new_address = input('Введите новый адрес:\n')
            ab[ch] = new_address
            print('Адрес успешно изменен')
            break
        else:
            print('Имя контакта не найдено')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто прервать функцию `return`:

```py
def change():
    while True:
        ch = input('\tВведите имя контакта чей адресс вы хотите изменить:\n')
        if ch == '':
            print('вы ничего не ввели')

        for c, v in ab.items():
            if c == ch:
                new_address = input('Введите новый адресс:\n')
                ab[c] = new_address
                print('Адресс успешно изменен')
                return
```

P.S. но вариант с управляющей переменной вместо `True` имхо более правильный (ответ CrazyElf).

Comment: Да нет, если больше никакой логики не должно быть дальше, то `return` в общем правильно вполне )

Answer (score 1):

Команда `break` завершает цикл `for`, а не `while`. Для цикла `while` команда `break` не используется, поэтому рекомендую заменить её на команду `return`.Это прервет всю функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Решил обновить свой вариант. Без `break` и т.п. Просто на `if` и повторном вызове функции.

```
def change():
    ch = input('\tВведите имя контакта чей адрес вы хотите изменить:\n')
    if ab.get(ch):
        ab[ch] = input('Введите новый адрес:\n')
        print('Адрес успешно изменен')
    elif ch == 'exit':
        print('Пока')
    else:
        change()

ab = {'Alex': 'info@example.org'}
change()
```